# Copy users between sitecollection in client side object model

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, patterns-and-practices

I invite **external users to a site collection** named "Extranet" in my Office365 tenant and **needs to give them access to a list in another site collection** so I'm doing a timer job for that.

My problem is that when the users accepts the invite they are added to the extranets allusers list but not to the other site collection so the users are not available to add in a Group in the other site collection.

I'm trying to add the new user to the site collection with the Web .EnsureUser but It cannot find user.

I'm using client side code in a Console Application so there are **no SPnnnnn objects available**

This is my code:

```
var web = extranetContext.Web;
User tempuser = web.SiteUsers.GetByEmail(mailToAddToGroup);
extranetContext.Load(tempuser);
extranetContext.ExecuteQueryRetry();
clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(tempuser.LoginName);
clientContext.ExecuteQueryRetry();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure here, but if I remember correctly you'll have to invite them to the other site collection as well for them to get access.